# Not able to connect to the remote server of neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to get the data from neo4j database which is at a remote location for which I make a ajax request which is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
//    headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
    url: "http://<mysite>.sb04.stations.graphenedb.com:24789/browser/",
     headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa('email' + ":" + 'mypw')
  },
    crossDomain: true,
    accepts: { json: "application/json" },
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        "query": "start n  = node(*) return n",
        "params": {}
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(textStatus);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

But I am getting this particular error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load . No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
>   is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8383'
>   is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code
>   403.

Please help to solve this...

Comment: I am not sure if it is related to your problem, but I added the following headers to my ajax request: 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Comment: Also, I believe the url for ajax requests for Neo4j looks different.

Comment: I'm founder & CEO of GrapheneDB. Unless you've put your database in read-only you need to move to a new database with updated credentials. By putting your credentials here you've given the entire internet read/write access to your database.

Comment: I edited out your credentials (even though people with enough rep can still see it in the edit history). You need to deal with this asap.

Comment: Oh ok, so the credentials you've put there don't look like the credentials we use for DB-level authentication, so 1) your database is not compromised BUT 2) you've exposed account level credentials which is even worse, because anyone can basically create, delete databases on your behalf, etc. The question has been edited, but the credentials will remain forever in the history. If it's a valid account, we will change the password, reset the API token and initiate a password reset.

Comment: For connecting to a database, please see the connection tab for connection endpoint and database-level authentication credentials. The username is **never** an email address.

Answer (score 0):

While setting up database server you have to whitelist the ip that may access it explicitly or add * so that all ip may access it.

Answer (score 0):

By default Neo4j only accept request from localhost.

- Do you have change param `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address` in `neo4j-server.properties` ?
- Do you have access to the browser ?

Moreover, you don't use the good endpoint : change `http://blackswantechnologiesosint.sb04.stations.graphenedb.com:24789/browser/` by http://blackswantechnologiesosint.sb04.stations.graphenedb.com:24789/db/data/transaction/commit`

See the documentation on this : http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api.html

Comment: IMPORTANT : you expose your database to internet with read & write operation ! It's not a good choice fro security reason, except if your database is in readonly mode